# Unable to get Web API controller method's URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.1

Env: C# Core 3.1 WebApi Project.

In my controller I'm trying to get the current URL but am getting a null value.  I've tried a number of things using the Url class:

```
var x = Url.Link("https://localhost:44397/api/Account/Accounts/", new { a = 1, b = 2 });
var y = Url.RouteUrl("www.xyz.com", new { a = 3, b = 4 });
var url = Url.Link("GetAuthors", authorsResourceParameters);
var r = Url.RouteUrl("This route");
var yd = Url.Action("myAction", "myController", authorsResourceParameters, "https");
```

The Url class is from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.EndpointRoutingUrlHelper.  Is this the correct namespace?

What am I missing?

Comment: why did you want to get the current URL?

Comment: Cause I want it.

Comment: well if we know the problem you're trying to solve, then maybe we can propose a better solution. Anyway, good luck with your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code:

```
var request = HttpContext.Request;

var uri = string.Concat(request.Scheme,"://",
                        request.Host.ToUriComponent(),
                        request.PathBase.ToUriComponent(),
                        request.Path.ToUriComponent(),
                        request.QueryString.ToUriComponent());
```

good luck.